# service reference is ignoring knowntype

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, known-types

```
[CollectionDataContract(Namespace = "CISICPD")]
[KnownType(typeof(List<CISICPD.LeeDictionary>))]
public class LeeDictionary : Dictionary<string, object> 
{
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "CISICPD")]
[KnownType(typeof(List<CISICPD.LeeDictionary>))]
public class TestResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<LeeDictionary> Results;

    public TestResponse() { Results = new List<LeeDictionary>(); }
    [OnDeserializing]
    private void OnDeserialize(StreamingContext c) { Results = new List<LeeDictionary>(); }
}
```

if the above is used in a service reference the generated `reference.cs` simply ignores the knowntypes specified above.

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="TestResponse", Namespace="CISICPD")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public partial class TestResponse : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
```

I specified the `LeeDictionary` so i could set my own namespace (thought it might be namespace issues), changing it to `Dictionary<string,object>` is just the same. The problem comes when the dictionary itself contains another dictionary and complains that the type is not known.

If I add the knowntype line to the `reference.cs` it then all works but I cant see why it wont put it in when generating the references?

Comment: The serializer understands a List<>. Don't include it. Just do [KnownType(typeof(CISICPD.LeeDictionary))]

Comment: it still ignores the knowntype if I change to the above - strange

Comment: From what you posted we can't see that it's ignoring it, can we? The second code snippet is cut short, it should include both the `Results` property as well as the `LeeDictionary` from reference.cs, I think. I've tried to repoduce your issue, but those two are generated properly for me.

Comment: as in `[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="TestResponse", Namespace="CISICPD")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public partial class TestResponse : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged { ....` should have `[KnownType(typeof(List<CISICPD.LeeDictionary>))]` but there is no sign of any knowntype in references.cs

Comment: this is the leedictionary in references.cs: `    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContractAttribute(Name="LeeDictionary", Namespace="Test", ItemName="KeyValueOfstringanyType", KeyName="Key", ValueName="Value")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    public class LeeDictionary : System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object> {
    }`